# Remove thousands separator in Calculator app of Samsung Galaxy S2 

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, calculator

Is there any way to tweak a standard Calculator application in Samsung Galaxy S2 mobile phone not to display the thousands separator?

I mean to display 1000 instead of 1,000. Is somehow related to locale?

Comment: It must be unique to the phone. My DROID doesn't use a thousands separator.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be a regional setting, I just changed the Locale on my original SGS from UK English to French and then German (picked as both of them format their thousands and decimals differently, and I can read them both) and it's stayed in `10,000.00` format each time, even after a reboot.

Answer (score 1):

No, there doesn't seem to be any configuration to remove the digit grouping on the stock calculator app.

If you are not particular about using that very app, you can try out some free calculator apps from the market. I tried [RealCalc Scientific Calculator](https://market.android.com/details?id=uk.co.nickfines.RealCalc&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsInVrLmNvLm5pY2tmaW5lcy5SZWFsQ2FsYyJd), and it's got an option in its Settings to remove digit grouping.